# Update column based on IF Else Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables A and B

**Table A**

```
ID_number as PK
first_name, 
L_Name
```

**Table B**

```
ID_number, 
Email_id,
Flag
```

I have several people who have multiple email ID and are already flagged as X on table B.

Whereas i am trying to find list of people who have an email id or multiple email ID, but were never flagged.

e.g `John clark` might have 2 email in table B, but was never flagged.

Comment: Please clarify your question some. Your subject heading mentions wanting to update a column based on a condition, however your text really only talks about selecting data conditionally. Perhaps you could also provide a sample of existing data and a sample of what you are looking for as a result. Take a look here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it has a lot of good information.

Comment: This would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I am trying to update the column_name "Flag" as X for the particular record having a lowest sequence number , if the persons email_id was never flagged previously.

Comment: Are you looking for a single update statement that updates the record for each unique `ID_number` group with the lowest `Email_id`, setting the `Flag` field to have the value `'X'`? Do you want it to also clear/null that `Flag` field for the other non-lowest `Email_id` records for each `ID_number` group?

Comment: I am just looking to update the column FLAG to be X with lowest email_ID (first email id recorded) if the person doesn't have any FLAG so far.

Comment: See my answer below, it is a self contained example that should do what you are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 
                  from b
                  where b.id_number = a.id_number and b.flag = 'X'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to perform an update, but your question seems to be only about selecting (probably to update based on select). It should be something like this:

```
SELECT A.L_Name
FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM B 
    WHERE B.ID_number = A.ID_number AND B.Flag = 'X'
)
```

`OR` the `LEFT JOIN` version

```
SELECT 1
FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.ID_number = A.ID_number AND B.Flag = 'X'
WHER B.ID_number IS NULL
```

Usually, the first version is faster than the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Forget Table A...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_number FROM table_b t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT NULL FROM table_b t2 WHERE t1.ID_number=t2.ID_number AND t2.flag='X'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your responses in the comments, I believe this is what you are looking for:

```sql
--drop table update_test;

create table update_test
(
    id_num      number,
    email_id    number,
    flag        varchar2(1) default null
);

insert into update_test values (1, 1, null);
insert into update_test values (1, 2, null);
insert into update_test values (2, 3, null);
insert into update_test values (2, 7, null);
insert into update_test values (3, 2, null);
insert into update_test values (3, 3, 'X');
insert into update_test values (3, 7, null);

select * from update_test;

select id_num, min(email_id)
from update_test
group by id_num;

update update_test ut1
set flag = case 
    when email_id = (
        select min(email_id) 
        from update_test ut2 
        where ut2.id_num = ut1.id_num
    ) then 'X' 
    else null end
where id_num not in (
    select id_num 
    from update_test
    where Flag is not null);
```

The last update statement will update and set the `Flag` field on the record for each `id_num` group with the lowest `email_id`. If the `id_num` group already has the `Flag` field set for one it will ignore it.